# What do the Pokéball upgrades do?

Tags: pokemon-pinball-ruby-and-sapphire

At the top of each table in *Pokémon Pinball: Ruby & Sapphire*, there are three lights which can temporarily upgrade your Pokéball to a higher tier. (Poké Ball, Great Ball, Ultra Ball, and Master Ball)

In the main series higher tier Poké Balls make Pokémon easier to catch, but in Pokémon Pinball they always take 3 hits to catch regardless of the ball type.

What do the Pokeball upgrades do in Pokémon Pinball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Pinball:_Ruby_%26_Sapphire#Pok.C3.A9_Ball), it multiplies the points you score:

> Fittingly with the other Pokémon-inspired tweaks to the basic pinball formula, the ball is a Poké Ball. Each table has three lights near the top of the upper half that, when lit simultaneously, will upgrade the Poké Ball temporarily to the next better basic Poké Ball; the upgrades are the Great Ball, the Ultra Ball, and the Master Ball. **Each upgrade multiplies the points gained on the table by a different multiplier: 2×, 3×, and 4×, respectively.**